# Non-trivial $C^{k_1}$ vector bundle that is trivial as $C^{k_2}$ fibre bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

For given $\infty \ge k_1 \ge k_2 \ge 0$, are there non-trivial $C^{k_1}$ vector bundles over a "sufficiently nice" space that are trivial as a $C^{k_2}$ fibre bundle? How nice can the space be and still admit counter-examples?